# How to get the ip address of a windows 7/8/8.1/10 phone programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, ip

i am new to this community & windows phone app development. I need to get the ip address of the network (wifi and mobile) to which the device is connected pro-grammatically on a windows phone app (C#). windows version 7/8/8.1/10 is required.

Comment: Have you tired anything?

Comment: @DavidPilkington I doubt the duplicate matches, as OP is specifically asking for Win7 upwards, not only for Win8.

Comment: Nope. Don't have much idea on how to proceed. See my aim is to track down the users who are using my webview Url. I suppose ip address will be a great method to uniquely  track users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string ip = "";
string strHostName = "";
strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

ip = addr[2].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a method like below

```
public static IPAddress GetIpAddress()
{
List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();

var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
foreach (var hn in hostnames)
{
    if (hn.IPInformation != null)
    {
        string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
        ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
    }
}

IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddresses[0]);
return address;
}
```

call the method whenever you need to get the ip address.